# Not able to have highcharts x-axis labels max

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to have limited number of labels in x-axis. but its not working.
below is my code. Please help me

```
xAxis: { max : 5,
                style: {
                    fontFamily : "Open Sans", 
                    fontweight: 700 ,

                },
        },`
```

Answer (score 0):

The `max` property is used to set maximum value of the axis. To set limited number of labels and ticks use `tickAmount` option:

```
xAxis: {
    tickAmount: 5,
    style: {
        fontFamily: "Open Sans",
        fontweight: 700,

    }
}
```

API Reference:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickAmount